# How to calculate the size a bounding box?

Tags: geometry

What formula could I use to calculate the size in Kilometres of a bounding box based on a given Southwest latitude/longitude and a Northeast latitude/longitude points?

The bounding box format is defined as:

```
bounds = sw_latitude,sw_longitude,ne_latitude,ne_longitude
```

Comment: Do you want lengths of the sides?  The area enclosed?

Comment: I would like to check that the size of the bounding box (defined by a Southwest latitude/longitude and a Northeast latitude/longitude geographic coordinate) is not larger than 20 Kilometres.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the Earth is a sphere (it's [not](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equatorial_bulge) quite), latitude and longitude form a system of coordinates $(\varphi, \theta)$, where $-\frac{\pi}{2} < \varphi < \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $-\pi < \theta < \pi$.  Note that $\varphi = 0$ is the equator and $\theta = 0$ is the prime meridian, through Greenwich, UK.

You are describing a region that is not actually a rectangle, bounded on the West and East by meridians (the lines of longitude $\theta_W$ and $\theta_E$) and bounded on the South and North by parallels (the lines of latitude $\varphi_S$ and $\varphi_N$).

The lengths of the West and East sides of the region (let's call them $\ell_W$ and $\ell_E$) are easier to calculate, being circular arcs along meridians, which are great circles (same radius as the Earth):
$$
\ell_W = \ell_E = R (\varphi_N - \varphi_S).
$$

The lengths of the South and North sides of the region (let's call them $\ell_S$ and $\ell_N$) are circular arcs along parallels, which are circles of a radius determined by the latitude:
$$
\ell_S = R(\theta_E - \theta_W)\cos \varphi_S
$$
and
$$
\ell_N = R(\theta_E - \theta_W)\cos \varphi_N.
$$

Thus, the total perimeter is
$$
P = 2R (\varphi_N - \varphi_S) + R(\theta_E - \theta_W)(\cos \varphi_S + \cos \varphi_N).
$$

*Note:*  Use $R = 6371$ km for the radius of the Earth, and if your coordinates are in degrees, then you need to multiply them by $\frac{\pi}{180}$ to get radian measure.

[image: Sphere with patch]

Answer (score 1):

Let $r$ be the radius, and $(\phi, \theta)$ represent a latitude & longitude.

Let the bounds be $(\phi_{sw}, \theta_{sw})$, $(\phi_{ne}, \theta_{ne})$.

Then the north-south boundaries have lengths $r(\phi_{ne}-\phi_{sw})$.

The northern east-west boundary has length $ r \cos \phi_{ne}(\theta_{ne}-\theta_{sw})$.

The southern east-west boundary has length $ r \cos \phi_{sw}(\theta_{ne}-\theta_{sw})$.

**Note**: The above is not quite correct. The north-south boundaries are unambiguous, but there are two possibilities for the east-west boundaries. The expression $(\theta_{ne}-\theta_{sw})$ should be $((\theta_{ne}-\theta_{sw}) \mod 2 \pi)$ or $(-(\theta_{ne}-\theta_{sw}) \mod 2 \pi$). Presumably you want the smaller of the two.